# How do I initialise a map within a map in F#

Tags: f#

I want a map of maps in F#, but I can't work out how to initialise it. Both

```
Map.empty.Add("Foo": Map.empty.Add(1: "a").Add(2, "b"))
```

and

```
Map.empty.Add("Foo": Map [ (1, "a"); (2, "b") ])
```

give me syntax errors, but the errors are just unexpected symbols (which doesn't really help me) or mismatched parentheses (but they are matched, so that must be because of the unexpected symbols). So how *do* I do it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use commas instead of colons throughout:

```ml
Map.empty.Add("Foo", Map.empty.Add(1, "a").Add(2, "b"))
```

Your idea of using the `Map` constructor instead is definitely easier to manage, but I think it's even better if used consistently at both levels:

```ml
Map [
    "Foo", Map [
        1, "a"
        2, "b"
    ]
]
```

Comment: That's it, thanks. I hope one day to get good enough at F# to understand why! :)

I take the point about using the Map constructor at each level. It will be machine generated code, so nobody will expect readability, but consistency should help debugging and maintenance.

Comment: @digitig, F# doesn't have special syntax for dictionaries. Instead this syntax creates list of tuples and initializes map from it